# How does Object class implement clone() method

Tags: java, class, object, clone

In a book on Core Java, I found this excerpt :

> Think about the way in which the
>   Object class can implement clone. It
>   knows nothing about the object at all,
>   so it can make only a field-by-field
>   copy. If all data fields in the object
>   are numbers or other basic types,
>   copying the fields is just fine. But
>   if the object contains references to
>   subobjects, then copying the field
>   gives you another reference to the
>   subobject, so the original and the
>   cloned objects still share some
>   information.

After reading this I was wondering, that `How is the clone method originally implemented in Object Class?`

What bothers me is that: how can a method in `Object` class make a field by field clone of a sub-class object, when it knows nothing about that class?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually, `clone()` is implemented in native code, so I assume it just does a memory copy (copy all the bytes) without knowing the contents.

Besides that, there is the Reflection API to gain knowlegde about a class (which would be slower, however).

Comment: Well, I dont' know about Reflection, I mean doing clone via Reflection would seem a pretty painstaking idea - I mean think about making all those Method, Field objects and calling all those getClass() ... eekkksss ... jUst sounds about very lengthy and tedious.   However, I would buy your argument on clone() being a native method. Since, under the norms of JLS, it is just not possible to define clone() in Object to be able to access the fields of all non-existence classes .   ----    AViD

Comment: In native code any reference to another object would be a pointer, so if you `clone()` an object using the default imlementation, what is copied is just the pointer. Thus the cloned object still references the objects the orignal points to. Primitive fields (like `int` etc.) are directly stored in the object (i.e. no pointer) so they would be copied.

Comment: Right. It does: VMMemoryManager.clone(this);

Comment: @O.D. depends on the implementation though, in Windows JDK 1.5 it's just `protected native Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException;`. But the result would be the same ;)

Comment: @VaidAbhishek: It doesn't need reflection, it just needs a bitwise copy. memcpy() for example. Your last sentence about non-existent classes doesn't make sense. You can't do anything with non-existent classes.

Answer (score 1):

Read this from the [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29):

> protected Object clone() -
>
> Creates and returns a copy of this
> object. The precise meaning of "copy"
> may depend on the class of the object.
> The general intent is that, for any
> object x, the expression:
>
> x.clone() != x
>
> will be true, and that the expression:
>
> x.clone().getClass() == x.getClass()
>
> will be true, but these are not
> absolute requirements. While it is
> typically the case that:
> x.clone().equals(x) will be true, this
> is not an absolute requirement. By
> convention, the returned object should
> be obtained by calling super.clone. If
> a class and all of its superclasses
> (except Object) obey this convention,
> it will be the case that
>
> x.clone().getClass() == x.getClass().
>
> By convention, the object returned by
> this method should be independent of
> this object (which is being cloned).
>
> **To achieve this independence, it
> may be necessary to modify one or more
> fields of the object returned by
> super.clone before returning it.
> Typically, this means copying any
> mutable objects that comprise the
> internal "deep structure" of the
> object being cloned and replacing the
> references to these objects with
> references to the copies. If a class
> contains only primitive fields or
> references to immutable objects, then
> it is usually the case that no fields
> in the object returned by super.clone
> need to be modified.**

Means when you have a subobject in your object you shouldnt just clone/copy its reference but the internal structure of this object (in order to create a new instance of it), if each object has its *clean* clone() methode you will be able to clone it like the parent object otherwise you will have to create a new instance of it and copy its internal premitive fields one by one.

Comment: This is all okay, wisdom about perfect recipe of clone() method, but I want to know how exactly is clone() implemented in Object class ... you have given no clue on that ... :-(

Comment: take a look at this source code of the clone method: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Object.java.html