# How does clone() method in java works?

Tags: java, object, clone

I know this question has been asked so many times.

First of all `Object.clone()` method in java is native method i.e. it is implemented in JVM and user doesn't need to know about it's implementation.

My question is whether this method is abstract too. If not why it has to be overridden in the class that we want to clone.

And one more question . 
It is overridden as follows

```
public Object clone() {
    MyClass obj;
    try {
        obj = (MyClass)super.clone();
    } catch(CloneNotSupportedException e) {
        Statements
    }
    return obj;
}
```

In the 4th line of this code we called , `super.clone()` method , which `clone()` method are we calling in this line and if `Object.clone()` method why did we override it , we can simply cast it wherever we want to clone the Object like

```
MyClass obj2 = (MyClass)obj1.clone();
```

and is their any way to know the coding of `Object.clone()` method?

Comment: `clone` is implemented in native lang http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5375311/how-does-object-class-implement-clone-method  and http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Object.java#Object.clone%28%29

Comment: why do we need to override this method?

Answer (score 3):

1. A method cannot be `native` and `abstract` at the same time because `native` is a statement about a specific implementation of a method;
2. `clone` must be overridden at least because `Object#clone` is `protected` to prevent access to clients in the case the object does not support cloning;
3. in many cases `clone` needs to do more than `Object#clone`, which just makes a binary copy of the original, which amounts to a *shallow* clone, with all the referenced objects staying the same;
4. there's no point in catching `CloneNotSupportedException` in the subclass: you should already know whether the superclass does or doesn't support cloning (it is not something which can change at runtime).

Answer (score 0):

`Object.clone()` is not abstract. Overriding it when implementing `Clonable` is just a convention. (`Clonable` is a marker interface - like `Serializable` etc.)

Overriding methods (should) always call `Object.clone()` directly or indirectly.

I think, casting it is not necessary because `Object.clone()` preserves the exact class. If you catch the `CloneNotSupportedException` you could even return `MyClass`.

As `Object.clone()` is implemented natively you would have to look at the sources of some JVM implementation like OpenJDK.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is whether it's abstract too

No it isn't, and the Javadoc already tells you that, as does the fact that Object itself isn't abstract, and it 'doesn't have to be overridden in the class we want to clone' unless you want to change the access permission, which has nothing to do with 'abstract': and you couldn't call 'super.clone()' in such an override unless it wasn't abstract.

In short, your question doesn't make much sense.